# Match Question Mark in mod_rewrite rule regex

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am looking to rewrite urls with multiple substrings.  One substring is being requested as a subdirectory, while any others are requested as normal query string parameters.

For example, I would like to rewrite urls from

```
http://www.mysite.com/mark/friends?page=2
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/friends.php?user=mark&page=2
```

I am able to accomplish this with the exception of the question mark character.  Here is my rewrite rule:

```
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/friends[?]?([^/\.]+)?$ friends.php?user=$1&$2 [L]
```

If I change the question mark to any other character it works great.  It seems like the problem is that the '?' character is being interpreted incorrectly as the start of a new query string.

I need to pass on any parameters that appear after /user/friends as is.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be using the `[QSA]` flag instead of trying to rewrite the query string. `[QSA]` passes on the query string to the rewritten URL.

So your rule should look like:

```
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/friends/? friends.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Your case is very similar to [the example given for using the QSA flag in the mod_rewrite cookbook](http://mod-rewrite.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Works really well & I'm reading the cookbook right now.

Comment: Supers solution it worked for me too, though I edited code to my conditions: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\.php? pindex.php?typeofpage=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 13):

The [query is not part of the URL path and thus cannot be processed with the `RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#rewriterule). This can only be done with the [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive (see `%{QUERY_STRING}`).

But [as Chad Birch already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-modrewrite-rule-regex/822439#822439) it suffices th set the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to automatically get the original requested query appended to the new URL.

Comment: QSA has a problem listed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468098/what-is-l-in-qsa-l-in-htaccess/16468677#comment79837245_16468677. Also, rewritecond query_string is not able to distinguish requests with no query strings, vs requests with naked query strings (ie a single question mark and nothing else). Is there a way to distinguish these two requests?

Comment: Ok nbm.. I've found it: `${the_request}`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the rewrite flag QSA, you can also use the QUERY_STRING environment variable as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/friends$ /friends.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And the URL in question

```
http://www.example.com/mark/friends?page=2
```

will be rewritten to (as specified):

```
http://www.example.com/friends.php?user=mark&page=2
```