# Can I pass matched variables to the new URL with mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, get

I'm quite experienced in PHP but I don't quite use `mod_rewrite` (although I should). All I want to ask is if it's possible to pass many variables through a single rewrite rule.

For example, is it possible to rewrite this:

```
localhost/test.php?id=1&name=test&var1=3
```

into this:

```
localhost/mysupertest/
```

and also use the same rewrite rule for different values?

```
localhost/test.php?id=5&name=another_name&var3=42
```

into

```
localhost/mysupertest/
```

I know it can be done using Ajax, cookie, session, or POST variables, but I really want to use GET variables.

Comment: Do you really want to redirect a request of `/test.php?id=1&name=test&var1=3` to `/mysupertest/`? Or rather the other way round, a request of `/mysupertest/` to `/test.php?id=1&name=test&var1=3`?

Comment: Basically i'd like to rewrite my pagination for an object category. Say i'm browsing category supertest. I don't want to show mysupertest/page/1/ or mysupertet/page/2 but mysupertest/ for each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, but you probably should be using the `[QSA]` option for mod_rewrite, which will append all the URL parameters from '`?`' onwards. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^mysupertest/? test.php [QSA]
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-modrewrite-rule-regex) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible.  Something like this would do it:

```
RewriteRule test.php\?(.*)$ mysupertest/
```

However, you will lose your variables if you do that, as it's effectively the same thing as accessing localhost/mysupertest directly, with no query string data.  If you want to keep the variables, perhaps in a REST-style url, you can use back-references to rewrite them.  As John mentioned, a back-reference is simply a set of brackets, and whatever matches inside them becomes a variable in a numeric ordering scheme.

```
RewriteRule test.php\?id=(.*)&name=(.*)&var3=(.*)  mysupertest/$1/$2/$3
```

With the above rule, accessing `test.php?id=567&name=test&var3=whatever` would be the same as accessing `mysupertest/567/test/whatever`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Anything you can match with your regex expression can be rewritten as any url.  Anytime you put part of your regex string inside of parenthesis ( ), it becomes a variable that can be used while rewriting.

You would want something like (I think):

> RewriteRule test.php\?id=[0-9]+&name=.+&var1=[0-9]+ mysupertest/

Answer (score 0):

The QUERY_STRING is not part of the URI. From the documentation for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **Note: Query String**
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables respectively.