# Mod Rewrite complete befuzzlement

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule subpage\?sid /index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

My request is `http://example.com/subpage?sid`

It keeps returning 404 Not Found, rather than redirecting to index.php

I have tried not escaping the ? and changing the request to `http://example.com/subpage\?sid`

I have tried loads of things to try get this working but am now stumped.

Comment: Did you tri `RewriteRule ^subpage\?sid /index.php` ? (Note the caret ^)

Comment: Now that I've already given an answer for this, it really belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: This is a kind of programming so it's OK on stackoverflow.

Comment: But it's not programming--it's a configuration issue. There's nothing wrong with the RE. Most importantly, the average SF user is going to be more knowledgeable about this than the average SO user; Antony's more likely to get better help on SF.

Comment: rewrite could go either way -- it's a little of both (programming + sysadmin)

Comment: I support Jeff's opinion, I'm actually a programmer with very little sysadmin skills, but still know what url rewriting is and how to use it, same as most programmers where I work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pass matched variables to the new URL with mod_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066454/can-i-pass-matched-variables-to-the-new-url-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QUERY_STRING is not part of the URI. From the documentation for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **Note: Query String**
>
> The *Pattern* will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

As the doc says, you'll need to use a RewriteCond, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sid([&=]|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?subpage /index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

If %{QUERY_STRING} truly isn't an option, try:

```
# Apache is supposed to use PCRE, but doesn't seem to like "\\s"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} subpage?sid[^!-~] [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?subpage /index.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also, you almost never need RewriteBase as you're using it ("RewriteBase /"). Comment the line and test it to be sure, but you'll probably find you can delete it with no ill affect.

Comment: I can't use just QUERY_STRING for complicated reasons, but your answer does make sense. The following Still gives me 404:  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} subpage\?sid$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: It's because "sid" isn't at the end of %{THE_REQUEST}; there's still the HTTP version. Why can't you use QUERY_STRING?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check the VirtualHost setting for your site and set the AllowOverride setting for the corresponding directory?

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/some_host>
     ....
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Here's more about apache's [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)