# mod_rewrite with multiple variables

Tags: mod-rewrite, iirf

I have a URL like so:

`http://localhost/deals/?search=fred` that redirects to `index.cfm?path=`

When I use mod rewrite the URL parameter becomes

```
path = /deals/?search=fred
```

I currently have `RewriteRule /(.*) /index.cfm?path=/$1 [L]`

How can I split it so I can actually use the URL variable "search"?

I am using IIRF rewrite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod Rewrite complete befuzzlement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807410/mod-rewrite-complete-befuzzlement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

thanks

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\?(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1&$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1&search=$2 [L]
```

However if you just wanna continue with what you use then you can simply use

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)[?](.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1?$2 [L]
```

OR it should be there by itself in the get variables and u can access it by something like

```
search = GET["search"]
```

Comment: hi this gets me close RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.cfm?path=$1&$2 [L] however i get ?search as a variable?

Comment: hi, i am not an newbie with cold fusion but i have slight idea that they should be something like how you got your path in the first place. So however you got your path, get your search like that as well.

Comment: yep sure.. thanks for your help.. it's jsut he variable becomes "?search" and to get it I need to url.?search.. which doesn't work.. I'll figure it out though.. thanks heaps :)