# How to escape “?” using regex in .htaccess for mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is wrong in this rule?

```
RewriteRule ^page\?v=([^/]+)$ page.php?v=$1 [L,NC]
```

I just want to make the URL looks like that

```
http://www.domainname.com/page?sk=info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to include the query parts if they're not changing anyway.

```
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php [L,NC]
```

The `RewriteRule` will not match any part of the query string. `page?v=123` will still become `page.php?v=123`

Also, your `RewriteRule` uses `?v=` while you talk about `?sk=info`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can find additional information about this mod_rewrite case here:
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

And another SO entry about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex).