# What is L in [QSA, L] in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, qsa

> QSA means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL,
>   it will be appended to the rewrite (olle?p=1 will be rewritten as
>   index.php?url=olle&p=1.
>
> L means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below
>   this one.

Hi, what are some easy examples to explain the use of L?
I can't seem to grasp this explanation above. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: QSA flag in mod_rewrite : https://helponnet.com/2021/04/27/htaccess-qsa-flag/

Answer (score 136):

### .htaccess flag list

- C (chained with next rule)
- CO=cookie (set specified cookie)
- E=var:value (set environment variable var to value)
- F (forbidden - sends a 403 header to the user)
- G (gone - no longer exists)
- H=handler (set handler)
- **L (last - stop processing rules)**

> Last rule: instructs the server to stop rewriting after the preceding directive is processed.

- N (next - continue processing rules)
- NC (case insensitive)
- NE (do not escape special URL characters in output)
- NS (ignore this rule if the request is a subrequest)
- P (proxy - i.e., apache should grab the remote content specified in the substitution section and return it)
- PT (pass through - use when processing URLs with additional handlers, e.g., mod_alias)
- R (temporary redirect to new URL)
- R=301 (permanent redirect to new URL)
- QSA (append query string from request to substituted URL)
- S=x (skip next x rules)
- T=mime-type (force specified mime type)

Flags are added to the end of a rewrite rule to tell Apache how to interpret and handle the rule. They can be used to tell apache to treat the rule as case-insensitive, to stop processing rules if the current one matches, or a variety of other options. They are comma-separated, and contained in square brackets.

Comment: You got my +1, but for a _perfect_ answer, it would be nice to provide a link to Apache's official resources, e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule (or wherever your reference was)

Answer (score 103):

The `QSA` flag means to append an existing query string *after* the URI has been rewritten. Example:

URL=`http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah`

Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1
```

Result=`/index.php?b=bar`

Notice how the `q=blah` is gone. Because the existing query string is dropped in favor of the one in the rule's target, (b=$1). Now if you include a `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1 [QSA]
```

The result becomes=`/index.php?b=bar&q=blah`

---

The `L` flag simply means to stop applying any rules that follow. Given the same URL, `http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah`, and given the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^foo - 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1
```

The first rule gets applied and the URI gets passed through unchanged (via the `-` target). The rewrite engine then processes the next rule, and the URI gets rewritten to `/bar.php?z=foo/bar`. What happens when you add an `L` to the end:

```
RewriteRule ^foo - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.php?z=$1
```

The URL `http://example.com/foo/bar` gets passed through untouched from the first rule, then **stops** because of the `L` flag. If the URL is `http://example.com/something/else` then the first rule doesn't match and the second rule gets applied, rewriting the URI to: `/bar.php?z=something/else`

Note that since the rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing, the `L` flag will *not* prevent the looping, only any further rules from getting applied in the current iteration.

Comment: QSA replaces `?` to `&`, making it impossible to distinguish between `/page&foobar` vs `/page?foobar`. How can I stop QSA from replacing `?` to `&`?

Comment: @Pacerier if you need to encode the query string in the new query string, then you may want to look into using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable instead of using QSA

Answer (score -1):

Example of [L,QSA]

> Before: *https://example.com/index.php?user=robert*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)?$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> After: *https://example.com/user/robert?query=value*

You can also use other query too.

> Like: *robert?query=value&query2=value2&query3=value3*