# mod_rewrite search url issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a single page app by loading view files into the template (index.php) - which is working well - except for searching.

My URL

```
http://testdomain.loc/members/search/?s=foo+bar
```

My Rule

```
RewriteRule ^members/search/(.*)$ index.php?view=members-search&keywords=$1 [L]
```

This is loading the correct view, but it's not passing the keyword parameters, so when I `print_r($_GET)`, this is what I see...

```
(
    [view] => members-search
    [keywords] => 
)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: take a look @QSA, =>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468098/what-is-l-in-qsa-l-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RewriteRule is only matching the *path*, not the query parameters. You'll want to append the original query parameters to the rewritten URL using `QSA`:

```
RewriteRule ^members/search/ index.php?view=members-search [L,QSA]
```

If you actually wanted to match on the query parameters, you'd have to do so in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^members/search/ index.php?keywords=%1 [L]
```

(Not quite sure if this will work exactly as is, but something along those lines. `QSA` will be a lot simpler either way.)

Comment: Or use: `RewriteRule ^members/search/ index.php?view=members-search&keywords=%1 [L]`

Comment: Your - and donald123's - suggestion to use QSA led me to the correct answer. Thanks!