# RewriteRule with 2 request parameters in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite URL using wordpress. like
`/name/1/2/` to `/name?last_name=1&first_name=2`
I've tried few ways. i.e. following code. But it seems not working well.
Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^name/(\d+)/(\d+)/ index.php?p=9&last_name=$1&first_name=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`RewriteRule ^name/(\d+)/(\d+)/ index.php?p=9&last_name=$1&first_name=$2 [QSA, L]`

You can refer to this post [What is L in [QSA, L] in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468098/what-is-l-in-qsa-l-in-htaccess) for understanding QSA and L flag.

> QSA means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL,
>   it will be appended to the rewrite (olle?p=1 will be rewritten as
>   index.php?url=olle&p=1.
>
> L means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below
>   this one.