# htaccess 3 different urls in one php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 3 step in one php file:
This is my htacess now:

```
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)$                         "/index.php?page=igra&id=$1"
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)/sezona/(.*)$                         "/index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2"
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)/sezona/(.*)/liga/(.*)$                         "/index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2&league=$3"
```

When i go in browser something like index.php?page=igra&id=$1 or index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2 or index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2&league=$3 sure with real values it works fine,  but when i try to access with this pretty links it always show me the first rewrite rule..

I hope u understand me what i need here, best regards..

Answer (score 1):

Your first rule is capturing everything, so the subsequent rules never get executed. Just switch them around:

```
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)/sezona/(.*)/liga/(.*)$ /index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2&league=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)/sezona/(.*)$           /index.php?page=igra&id=$1&season=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^igra/(.*)$                       /index.php?page=igra&id=$1 [L]
```

Notice also the addition of the [`L`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468098/what-is-l-in-qsa-l-in-htaccess#:%7E:text=L%20(last%20%2D%20stop%20processing%20rules)&text=Flags%20are%20added%20to%20the,a%20variety%20of%20other%20options.) flag.

Comment: hmm, thanks but this is something strange , i need to be links like igra/../sezona/../liga it seams like he now automaticaly change to links like /index.php?page=igra&id=1....

Comment: Try now, just remove the `,R=301`.

Comment: same thing .. :)

Comment: any solution @BenM?