# Mod Rewrite faux-directory path with extra query string

Tags: php, apache, api, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file that has the following behavior. I'm doing it for an API which is located at a real location in the form of:

```
https://www.domain.com/apifolder/entry.php?call=testcall&data=testdata
```

The API call is routed starting from *entry.php* and eventually delivers the appropriate response. Essentially my entire API lands upon a large switch statement of valid API calls. The problem is, that URL is not very nice. I'm trying to replace it with a URL of this form:

```
https://www.domain.com/api/testcall?data=testdata
```

I have gotten close with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/? /apifolder/entry.php?call=$1 [L]
```

However, the desired example above does not work, because there first parameter that seems to coming in (*data*, which is in reality the second parameter), is led by a **?**. If I try the url:

```
https://www.domain.com/api/testcall&data=testdata
```

where it's led by a **&** instead, then it works perfectly fine. This looks weird to me too, sadly. Is there anything I can do to let the rewritten URL take in the query string beginning with a **?** instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by including the [QSA] flag in the rule, which passes the query string (in its desirable format) to the real URL:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/? /apifolder/entry.php?call=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried it after seeing this StackOverflow answer: [Match Question Mark in mod_rewrite rule regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex)