# .htaccess fails on HTTP GET with questionmark

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried almost every possible "solution" that I could find online for this matter, including Stackoverflow.

I am trying to rewrite

> http://example.com/index.php?view=search&q=something

to

> http://example.com/search/?q=something

When searching for something, the searchform direct's you to

> search/?q=this

But "**/search/**" is allread passed once so it has already used the questionmark
now i'm stuck with the script redirecting every search with a questionmark while it should be an "&" sign.

It works if I manualy change the ? to &.

Can someone pleas help me make it work with the Questionmark?

Here is a copy of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

ErrorDocument 404 /test.php


RewriteRule ^nothingfound/ test.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+) /index.php?view=search&q=%1


RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)*/$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)*/$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/*/$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2&letter=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)*/$ index.php?view=$1&task=$2&letter=$3&page=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/*/$  index.php?view=$1&id=$2&title=$3&page=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/*/$  index.php?view=$1&id=$2&title=$3&list=$4 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to understand your problem. Could you please provide a list of a few example urls, how they are currently rewritten and what the issue is with that?

Comment: http://example.com/blogs/top/ for example is = http://example.com/index.php?view=blogs&task=top

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see the problem here. I am out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)[qv]=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(search)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Replace this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+) /index.php?view=search&q=%1
```

with this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bq=
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?view=search [QSA,L]
```