# How to use question marks as a normal char in regular expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm working with apache mod_rewrite that suppots perl regex.
How can I use question mark as a normal char?
for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*/service/City?name)=(.*)-(.*)$
```

Comment: mod_rewrite uses PCRE, so `\?`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't match query string using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`. You will need to use `QUERY_STRING` variable for that. So correct way will be this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)-(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*/service/City)$
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also have a look here :

[Match Question Mark in mod_rewrite rule regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex)

since you are working with mod_rewrite you might want to hide your ? completely. The post above will explain how to do that.