# Point a Virtual Directory in IIS to another server IP

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, server

I have the following setup:-

### IIS Server 7

- domain            : abc.xyz.com
- virtual directory : abc.xyz.com/myapp/

### NGINX Server

- 192.168.23.122

My requirement is to whenever someone opens abc.xyz.com/myapp/ it should point to NGINX IP internally but the URL in the address bar should be abc.xyz.com/myapp/ and further links and navigation within the application should happen.

- NGINX server is accessible from the IIS server using IP.

### Current Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyRuleForNginx" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://192.168.1.105/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I am hitting the url:

> http://localhost/myapp/
>
> 192.168.1.105 is a nginx server on other system which I am able to access from the IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) which allows for cross-ASP.NET-application rewrites, which cannot be done with the built-in IIS rewrite module.

*(Please note that it seems [I'm wrong on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576989/point-a-virtual-directory-in-iis-to-another-server-ip/34579470#comment56904189_34579470)).*

They are having a `.htaccess`-like syntax for writing the rewrite/proxy rules, e.g.:

```
...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/myapp/(.*?)$ http://localhost/myapp/ [QSA,P]
...
```

(This is untested, just to give an idea).

The `QSA` parameters are present, because [a rewrite rule cannot capture URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822439/107625).

Comment: It's possible and I'm using for years. The key is you also need to install official Application Request Routing module.

Comment: Good to know, @Kul-Tigin. I've never managed to get it working with the built-in IIS module. Will upvote your answer now :-).