# Why url rewrite can't capture my last group with lookahead in the group before?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, capture, regex-lookarounds

I try to rewrite this URL. Group 4 is optional and looks until question mark. Group 5 must be captured even without g4 or slashes. Group 4 must be captured without Group 3.

```
https://www.example.de/prefix/group1/group2/group3-suffix/group4(optional)?group5
```

The Regex seems to work exactly as needed in most regex flavors, but in my .htaccess, group 5 is always empty.

My rewrite looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^prefix/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-suffix?/?((?:(?![?/]).)*)/?\??(.*)?/?$ /target.jsp?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3&g4=$4&$5 [L]
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Because `?group5` is a query string?!

Comment: G5 would be everything after the questionmark. Indeed this can be a query string. G4 looks until the qm or a forward slash.

Comment: `RewriteRule` doesn't look at query strings, hence results differ.

Comment: I wish to had never asked this question. You brought me to the right path. I need to use RewriteCond to get the query params.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match Question Mark in mod\_rewrite rule regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822421/match-question-mark-in-mod-rewrite-rule-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `RewriteRule` doesn't look at query strings you need to use a predefined flag to append old query strings to target URL known as **[`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)**

```
RewriteRule ^prefix/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-suffix?/?([^/]*)/?$ /target.jsp?g1=$1&g2=$2&g3=$3&g4=$4 [L,QSA]
```